Closed subspaces of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ that is not isomorphic to a subspace of a space with an unconditional basis
It is known that $L^1([0,1])$ does not admit any unconditional basis. Even more, $L^1([0,1])$ is not isomorphic to a subspace of a space with an unconditional basis.
My question is the following ``Give a closed subspace $S$ of $L^1([0,1])$, under what conditions is $S$ not isomorphic to a subspace of a space with an unconditional basis?
"
I tried to find references along this direction, but couldn't. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
